# Free download manager (using wine) browser (in ubuntu) integration?

Tags: wine, google-chrome, crossplatform

i'm a new windows to Linux immigrant. I personally love Free download manager (.exe) for  downloading. i installed it on Ubuntu using wine. it works perfectly. but how do i configure for browser integration?

That is chrome in Ubuntu browser integrated with FDM in wine !

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: you might like, [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). Download manager for Firefox. Support resume, link grabber and much more advance setting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually integrate FDM with chrome on Linux. For browser integration FDM uses npapi plugin which runs as a service on Windows. On Linux, I suppose Wine doesn't support running Windows services. You will need to recompile the plugin on Linux for that. If you use firefox you can use flashgot addon.

If you want to use Linux alternatives, you can try out [FlareGet](http://flareget.com/download) which supports browser integration with all the browsers - firefox, chrome and opera. There is just one limitation with the free version that it allows only two segments per download if file size is greater than 25 MB.